# Time Series Analysis for Non-Uniform Data

Tags: r, time-series

I have wait-time data for a coffee shop for 4 weeks. Since the data is crowdsourced, it is sparse and non-uniform along the time. So my question is: how should I deal with this non-uniform data? What are the some methods in time series forecasting that can handle non-uniform data? Or is there any way to make the data uniform?

Comment: It depends on what you wish to predict with your model. Your options can vary from seasonal differencing, resampling, to kalman filtering.

Comment: I want to predict how the crowdsourced data can be used to predict the future wait-times of the coffee shop. I also have a ground truth wait-times for the coffee shop, so I can make comparisons.

Comment: Try intermittent demand forecasting methods.

Answer (score 1):

Although not quite made for data for the coffee shop, you can have a look at the [Autoregressive Conditional Duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_duration) model. It was originally made for waiting times of trades data in finance but i suggest you should give it a shot. and please do report the results you got. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

wait time is probably dependent on the hour of the day so it makes sense too build a model by hour and by day. We are currently proposing this to Taco Bell who wishes to forecast each store in 15 minute intervals while also taking into account day-of-the-week, holidays, special events , price/promotion etc.. Consider putting up your data and perhaps we can take a look at it as your problem is everybody's problem.